# is any other way to do in dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

while answering one question i got struck with other question in mind.when it is normal pivot it is working fine but if i'm trying to do Dynamic query when the problem arises

after answering he asked for Dynamic Pivot

[PIVOT the date column in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476262/pivot-the-date-column-in-sql-server-2012/31477296?noredirect=1#)

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null
begin
drop table #temp
end


CREATE  table #temp (dated varchar(10),E1 int,E2 int,E3 int,E4 int)
insert into #temp
(dated,E1,E2,E3,E4)values 
('05-27-15',1,1,2,3),
('05-28-15',2,3,NULL,5),
('05-29-15',3,4,null,2)

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(max)
,@columns NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @columns = ISNULL(@columns + ', ', '') + N'[' + tbl.dated + ']'
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT dated
   FROM #temp
   ) AS tbl


SELECT @statement = 'Select P.col,MAX('+@columns+') from ( 
select col,' + @columns + ' from (
select * from #temp
CROSS APPLY(values(''E1'',E1),(''E2'',E2),(''E3'',E3),(''E4'',E4))cs (col,val))PP
PIVOT(MAX(val) for dated IN  (' + @columns + ')) as PVT)P
GROUP BY P.COL
'
PRINT @statement
EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @statement
```

my problem is how can i take MAX() conditions for the all dates dynamically like 
max(05-27-15),max(05-28-15) etc dates are coming dynamically how to assign max condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the `MAX` aggregate to column list `variable` will fix the issue

```
DECLARE @statement      NVARCHAR(max),
        @columns        NVARCHAR(max),
        @select_columns NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @select_columns = Isnull(@select_columns + ', ', '')+ N'MAX([' + tbl.dated + '])'
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT dated
        FROM   #temp) AS tbl

SELECT @columns = Isnull(@columns + ', ', '') + N'[' + tbl.dated+ ']'
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT dated
        FROM   #temp) AS tbl

SELECT @statement = 'Select P.col,' + @select_columns
                    + ' from ( 
    select col,' + @columns
                    + ' from (
    select * from #temp
    CROSS APPLY(values(''E1'',E1),(''E2'',E2),(''E3'',E3),(''E4'',E4))cs (col,val))PP
    PIVOT(MAX(val) for dated IN  (' + @columns
                    + ')) as PVT)P
    GROUP BY P.COL
' 


PRINT @statement
EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @statement
```

Comment: it is showing syntax error what ever the code you have posted

Comment: may be you have added max in declared statement but it wont in pivot taking max() condition